# Flutter Dependency Error 'have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?'

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error when I try to 'flutter run' my project.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.11.0+1\android\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_admob'.
> Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_admob'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My pubspec.yaml already have `firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1`.
I tried some solutions:

- Flutter clean
- Flutter pub get
- Flutter packages get
- Flutter upgrade

My app/build.gradle have compileSdkVersion defined `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 29`

Comment: According to the error message, seems like you are missing the `firebase_core` instead of the `firebase_admob`. Have you added that to the `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: same problem here, have you found the solution?

Comment: @DhimasPutera I don't remember. I guess I removed `Firebase_message` dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

The error says *"Could not find the [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) FlutterFire plugin"*. Did you add that one ? It's required to use any other FlutterFire package.

Comment: Yes. Everything is added
`firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1
firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14`

Comment: Does `flutter pub get` run without issues ?

Comment: Yes. Without any warning. My project was running last day, When I tried to update all dependencies, using `flutter pub outdated` and `flutter pub upgrade` this error appeared.